# How to get Vocabulary with weights for tf-idf word bags in ml.net?

Tags: c#, tf-idf, ml.net

The documentation of ML.NET shows how to use `context.Transforms.Text.ProduceWordBags` to get word bags. The method takes `Transforms.Text.NgramExtractingEstimator.WeightingCriteria` as one of the parameters, so it's possible to request `TfIdf` weights to be used. The simplest example would be:

```
// Get a small dataset as an IEnumerable and then read it as a ML.NET data set.
IEnumerable<SamplesUtils.DatasetUtils.SampleTopicsData> data = SamplesUtils.DatasetUtils.GetTopicsData();
var trainData = ml.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(data);

var pipeline = ml.Transforms.Text.ProduceWordBags("bags", review, ngramLength: 1, weighting: Transforms.Text.NgramExtractingEstimator.WeightingCriteria.TfIdf);

var transformer = pipeline.Fit(trainData);
var transformed_data = transformer.Transform(trainData);
```

That's all fine, but how do I get the actual results out of `transformed_data`?

I did some digging in a debugger, but I'm still quite confused on what's actually happening here.

First of all, running the pipeline adds three extra columns to `transformed_data`:

[image]

After getting a preview of the data I can see what's in these columns. To make things clearer here's what `GetTopicsData` returns, which is what we're running our transform on:

```
animals birds cats dogs fish horse
horse birds house fish duck cats
car truck driver bus pickup
car truck driver bus pickup horse
```

That's exactly what I'm seeing in the very first `bags` column, typed as `Vector<string>`:

[image]

Moving on to the second `bags` column, typed as `Vector<Key<UInt32, 0-12>>` (no idea what `0-12` is here btw.).

This one has `KeyValues` annotation on it and it looks like for each row it maps the words into indexes in global *Vocabulary* array.

[image]

The *Vocabulary* array is part of `Annotations`:

[image]

So that's promissing. You'd think the last `bags` column, typed as `Vector<Single, 13>` would have the weights for each of the words! Unfortunately, that's not what I'm seeing. First of all, the same *Vocabulary* array is present in `Annotations`:

[image]

And the values in rows are `1`/`0`, which is not what TfIdf should return:

[image]

So to me that looks more like "Is word `i` from the *Vocabulary* present in current row" and not the TfIdf frequency of it, which is what I'm trying to get.

Comment: OK. I think I got it. There is a bug in ML.NET which basically ignores `weighting` parameter in this scenarios and always uses `Tf`.